# Assigning group ID for CListCtrl C++

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I'm currently using a [derived class of `CListCtrl`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29064/CGridListCtrlEx-Grid-Control-Based-on-CListCtrl) to build my application upon. I'm trying to add an item to the list, and immediately assign it to a group:

```
// int row, int grp_id, CString header; - all initialized previously
int ind = m_list.InsertItem(row, header);
VERIFY(m_list.SetRowGroupId(row, grp_id));
```

Here's an implementation of `SetRowGroupID()`:

```
BOOL CGridListCtrlGroups::SetRowGroupId(int nRow, int nGroupId)
{
    //OBS! Rows not assigned to a group will not show in group-view
    LVITEM lvItem = { 0 };
    lvItem.mask = LVIF_GROUPID;
    lvItem.iItem = nRow;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.iGroupId = nGroupId;
    return SetItem(&lvItem);
}
```

Nothing too fancy here.

However, the **code is asserting false for `VERIFY()`.**

While I was searching through MSDN documents to find out why, it seems that the flag I want to use as a mask isn't available for this purpose (refer to [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/a8dbw8bc.aspx)).

Am I not able to change the group ID this way? For the record, I've also tried to use `MoveItemToGroup()`, which gave me the same result (that is, the item doesn't show up while group view is enabled).

Comment: See [LVITEM structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb774760) under `LVIF_GROUPID`: "If this flag is not set when an LVM_INSERTITEM message is sent, the value of iGroupId is assumed to be I_GROUPIDCALLBACK."  This implies that the group ID must be set at insertion time and can't be changed.

Comment: Are you trying to insert a new item, or update an existing item, as Mark assumes?

Comment: @MarkRansom If I attempt to call `InsertItem()` with a `LVITEM` specified, it fails to insert one whenever `LVIF_GROUPID` is set.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say why updating a member's group ID does not work directly.

However, setting `.iGroupId = I_GROUPIDCALLBACK` triggers the message `LVN_GETDISPINFO` and in its handler you can then assign the group ID.

Outline:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGridListCtrlGroups, CListCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(LVN_GETDISPINFO, OnGetDispInfo)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CGridListCtrlGroups::CGridListCtrlGroups(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMLVDISPINFO* dispInfo = LPNMLVDISPINFOW(pNMHDR);
    LVITEM* item = &dispInfo->item;

    if (item->mask & LVIF_GROUPID) {
        // assign group id
        item->iGroupId = ...;
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}

BOOL CGridListCtrlGroups::RequeryRowGroupId(int nRow)
{
    LVITEM lvi = {
        .mask = LVIF_GROUPID,
        .iItem = nRow,
        .iGroupId = I_GROUPIDCALLBACK
    };
    return SetItem(&lvi);
}
```